# How to make a vertical html5 progress bar in Google Chrome

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to make vertical HTML5 progress bar in Google Chrome?

In Mozilla Firefox, it can be done in the following way:

```
<style>
    .vert {
        -moz-orient: vertical;
    }
</style>
<progress class="vert" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px;"
value="10" max="100" id="progressBar">No progress bar</progress>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could rotate it:

Webkit: `-webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);`

FireFox: `-moz-transform: rotate(90deg);`

IE: `filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=1);`

Comment: -webkit-transform rotated it, but the position of the elemet is different to (0,0) now

Comment: Looks like such style is a solution:


    `-webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg) translateY(-1000%);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 0%;`

Comment: The style I posted above solved my problem. But maybe there is a better solution exists ...

Comment: I don't see how it could get any easier than that.

Comment: @MattK this comes with a lot of constraints. E.g. width/height references.

Comment: @OddDev can you elaborate?

Comment: @MattK Specs are: In case it's horizontal, fill out the remaining space (width: 100%). In case it's vertical, fill out the remaining space (height: ???). 

Comment: That seems like a completely different question than what was asked, try posting a new question to get your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `-webkit-box-orient`.

Checkout the [box model playground](http://flexiejs.com/playground/?random) from [Flexie](https://github.com/doctyper/flexie).

Comment: The first link is down now, I think, it shows a ton of tracking if you visit it